# Why can't I reuse a function in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Why does the below LINQ to SQL statment throw an exception?

I have a function

```
bool TrimAndCompare(string s1, string s2)
{
   return customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim()
}
```

...some other function i call the above function in my linq statement

```
var customers = from customer in _context.Customers
                          where
                              TrimAndCompare(customer.CustomerID, customerID)
                      select customer;
```

The above LINQ to SQL statment function throws an exception
but the below doesn't Why??

```
var customers = from customer in _context.Customers
                      where
                            customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim()
                      select customer;
```

I get a 'System.NotSupportedException'
where I try to access customers

Answer (score 8):

In the second snippet, the logic is being translated into a lambda expression which is then compiled into an expression tree... the two query translations are:

```
_context.Customers
        .Where(customer => TrimAndCompare(customer.CustomerID, customerID);
```

vs

```
_context.Customers
        .Where(customer => customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim());
```

LINQ to SQL knows how to handle expression trees, and it knows about `Trim`, and string equality. It *doesn't* know how to handle calls to arbitrary methods you've written.

The simplest approach to this is probably to change your method to this:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> CustomerIdMatches(string customerID)
{
   return customer => customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim()
}
```

You can then use:

```
from customer in context.Customers.Where(CustomerIdMatches(customerID))
... rest of query here
```

Or you could even make your own extension method to do the `Where` part as well.

Making it more generally reusable for different fields is slightly tricky. In particular, it's not going to work well from query expressions... it's doable, but not terribly pretty.

The usage would look something like this:

```
var query = context.Customers
                   .Where(TrimAndCompare(customer => customer.CustomerID,
                                         customer => customerID));
```

Not terribly nice :(

Comment: Well that is alright when I am trying to get a boolean value back. But what if I want to do something like. 

var customers = from customer in _context.Customers
                          where
                              customer.GetID() == "a"
                      select customer;

Comment: @soldierman: The point is that a `Where` expression *does* return a Boolean value. You compose that function as part of the query - note that all my examples call `Where`. The point is that it creates an expression tree with the right logic in, so that you can include that expression tree within the rest of the query.